# How to draw an image and save it into a file?

Tags: python, image

I want to create a new bitmap and draw something on it. Then save it into a png/jpg file. I don't know how to start. Is there a library can do this?

PS: I need to draw some Unicode characters (Chinese Characters).

Comment: Have you tried going to google's search page and typing "python draw bitmap" ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I tried to search "python draw save image" and only find some tutorials about modify existing image. Your keyword is better. I will have a try. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imaging library can do this, as can pillow.